# Is it possible to move my Kotlin files into separate package (source type) in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

default folder structure look like this:

```
app:
-manifests
-java
-res
```

Is there a way that I can create another folder here just for kotlin? So it gonna look like this:

```
app:
-manifest
-java
-kotlin
-res
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible. Add the folder called `kotlin` and after that add the following lines to the `android` section of your `app/build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
```

If you want to read more about Kotlin-Android projects in Android Studio, you can read [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html).

Answer (score 4):

Of course, just mark the folder as [source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html). Actually, default Gradle Kotlin plugin automatically recognizes `src/main/kotlin` and `src/main/java` as source folders.

Comment: Can't find this option in Android Studio :(

Comment: My Android Project View show only Java one, even if project view reconize  kotlin as source folder

Comment: Have you tried using a build automation system, like Gradle? Setting up source folders and dependencies by hand might quickly become tedious. Your problem would be solved by adding a single line to the `build.gradle` file.